# Unexpected token return Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, syntax

Could Someone please tell me what is wrong with that code ?

```
render () {
    return (
    <div className="user-detail-component">
      <h1>{this.props.match.params.userName}</h1>
      <table className="table table-hover table-responsive user-list-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>{'User Name'}</td>
            <td>{'Login Time'}</td>
            <td>{'Login Token'}</td>
            <td>{'App Token'}</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          { this.renderLoginList() }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    );
}
```

I am getting error:

> 2:33  error  Parse errors in imported module './UserDetailComponent': Line 27: Unexpected token

Line 27 is where return statement starts

Comment: try removing `{this.renderLoginList()}` and see if that fixes the issue. Maybe that line is the culprit

Comment: yes It worked ! problem is on rederloginlist function thank you.